# Scientific / Chemistry search interpreting

Tags: search-engine, node.js, text-processing

I'm trying to write a program where people can find company-specific information about substances. For example about the company's safety rules, information about vendors, basic information like molar mass, etc.

I was thinking about building my own search engine / search interpreter which identifies search queries e.g. CAS xxxx-xxx-xx or actual molecule names e.g. Benzoic Acid. However as there are much names in multiple languages for substances and people often use names other than the IUPAC standard, this would cost a lot of work.

Now there are existing search engines that use this, e.g. ChemSpider, WolframAlpha, etc. I assume most of them use closed source search engines / interpreters but I was wondering if there is any open source search interpreter for chemistry. NodeJS is preferred but other languages shouldn't be a huge problem, i could proxy it through.